# How to make stitches invisible

Tags: sewing

I'm working on a DIY kit of a plush doll. This is the first time I'm sewing. Per instructions, I'm using a back stitch to sew together two fleece pieces.
The problem is that the stitches are visible from the outside, and I think they should be invisible.
Did I sew it in a wrong way? Or is there something else I should have done?

Here is how it looks from the inside:
[image: Inside view]

And from the outside:
[image: outside view]

(Click on images to enlarge)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the least visibility when you use the same colour of yarn as your fabric.
But as a beginner, it will be easier when the yarn stands out from the fabric, which does make for the stitches to be seen a bit.

I guess the blue line in the picture is the line to sew on, if so, sew on that line and not near it. The better the stitches are in one line, the less visible they will be in the end.

Also remember to keep the stitching tight, not drawing the fabric together but many smallish stitches where the yarn is flat on the fabric, so that when you look between the layers of the fabric, the fabric will be close together and there is no space for it to move.

Comment: Thank you. Two follow-up questions: 1. What do you mean by "not drawing the fabric together"? 2. What yarn color should be picked in a situation like this, where I need to sew together two differenet colors (grey and white)?

Comment: @HeyJude either white or light gray would be preferable to that dark thread. If you go to a sewing shop you could probably find a color in between the two that would be relatively low visibility as the two colors aren't that different.

Comment: What I mean by 'drawing the fabric together' is that you make little 'hills and valleys', so by 'not drawing the fabric together' you leave it flat, but with no extra space between the layers. And as @Catija says, the colours of the fabrics or something in between for your yarn would work well. But for a first project, yarn you can see well is better than the best colour, to make it easier for you.

Comment: Question: would it be possible to remove your basting stitches (those hand-done backstitches in the first photo) after you sew/attach those  fleece pieces together, or after that part of the doll is finished?  It also seems likely that you could use a very long running stitch (either by machine or hand) to baste those pieces together - it would go a lot faster.  I sew with two layers of fleece quite a lot, and to me your instructions seem a little complicated for such a simple (appearing) step.  But I don't have the big picture of your project…  Good Luck!